# Python comparison

Tags: python, compare

Is there a more elegant way to make this comparison?
I cant imagine, check if received value is `>` or `<`.

```
range_1 = 1000

percent_1 = 10

range_2 = 1500

percent_2 = 15

range_3 = 1500.01

percent_3 = 20
```

```
class UtilsPurchase:
    @classmethod
    def calculate_cashback(cls, purchase_value):

        if purchase_value <= range_1:
            result = D(purchase_value / 100) * D(percent_1)
            return {'percent': percent_1, 'calculated_value': D(result)}

        if range_1 < purchase_value <= range_2:
            result = D(purchase_value / 100) * D(percent_2)
            return {'percent': percent_2, 'calculated_value': D(result)}

        if purchase_value >= range_3:
            result = D(purchase_value / 100) * D(percent_3)
            return {'percent': percent_3, 'calculated_value': D(result)}
```

Comment: Did you think about or tried to make a separate method for the redundant code?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `if`, `elif`, and `else` statements to combine the three separate `if` statements into one conditional statement.

For instance:

```
if purchase_value <= range_1:
    result = D(purchase_value / 100) * D(percent_1)
    return {'percent': percent_1, 'calculated_value': D(result)}

elif purchase_value <= range_2:
    result = D(purchase_value / 100) * D(percent_2)
    return {'percent': percent_2, 'calculated_value': D(result)}

else:
    result = D(purchase_value / 100) * D(percent_3)
    return {'percent': percent_3, 'calculated_value': D(result)}
```

This would also solve the issue of your code not being able to perform calculations on a `purchase_value` that is between 1500 and 1500.01 (with the above code it would go into the `else` section).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by putting everything you repeat into a function:

```
class UtilsPurchase:
    @classmethod
    def calculate_cashback(cls, purchase_value):
        if purchase_value <= range_1:
            return cashback_helper(purchase_value, percent_1)

        elif purchase_value <= range_2:
            return cashback_helper(purchase_value, percent_2)

        elif purchase_value >= range_3:
            return cashback_helper(purchase_value, percent_3)


    def cashback_helper(purchase_value, percent):
        result = D(purchase_value / 100) * D(percent)
        return {'percent': percent, 'calculated_value': D(result)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty close to a text-book use case for the bisect module from the standard Python library. See the  [first example in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#examples). You can give the the breakpoints, the `purchase_value`s and a particular value, it will tell what index you need, which you can use to find the percent you are interested in.

You haven't told us what `D()` does so I'm just using an identity function:

```
from bisect import bisect 

def D(v):
    return v

class UtilsPurchase:
    ranges = [1000, 1500]
    percents = [10, 15, 20]

    @classmethod
    def calculate_cashback(cls, purchase_value):
        percent = percents[bisect(ranges, purchase_value)]
        result = D(purchase_value / 100) * D(percent)
        return {'percent': percent, 'calculated_value': D(result)}

UtilsPurchase.calculate_cashback(1100)
# {'percent': 15, 'calculated_value': 165.0}

UtilsPurchase.calculate_cashback(5)
# {'percent': 10, 'calculated_value': 0.5}
```

This makes it easy to add more breakpoints without strings of if/elif blocks.

Answer (score 0):

This may reduce lines of code and avoid extra checking :

```
def GetFormattedResult(percent, purchase_value):
    result = D(purchase_value / 100) * D(percent)
    return {'percent': percent, 'calculated_value': D(result)}

class UtilsPurchase:
    @classmethod
    def calculate_cashback(cls, purchase_value):

        if purchase_value <= range_1:
            GetFormattedResult(purchase_value, range_1)

        elif range_1 < purchase_value <= range_2:
            GetFormattedResult(purchase_value, range_2)

        else: purchase_value >= range_3:
            GetFormattedResult(purchase_value, range_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to minimize duplicated code. You can see all 3 of your if statements are almost entirely the same.

```py
cutoffs = [1000, 1500, float("inf")]
percentages = [10, 15, 20]

for cutoff, percentage in zip(cutoffs, percentages):
    if purchase_value <= cutoff:
        result = D(purchase_value / 100) * D(percentage)
        return {'percent': percentage, 'calculated_value': D(result)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```py
def calculate_cashback(purchase_value):
    values=[1000,1500]
    cashback=[0.10,0.15,20]
    c = 0
    for(i,t in enumerate(values)):
        if purchase_value > t:
            c = i+1
        else
            break
    
    return {'percent':cashback[c]*100,'calculated_value':purchase_value*(1-cashback[c]) }
```

Note, `'percent'` will be return as a full integer and not a decimal. You can change it according to your needs.